# Raising vector with negative numbers to a fractional exponent in R

Tags: r, math

I have a vector of numbers that contains negative numbers and I would like to raise it to a fractional exponent, but can't quite figure out how to do it. Here is some example code.

```
a = seq(5,-5,1)
b = a^(5/2)
```

`b` returns `NAN` values when `a` is negative. However,

```
d = -5^(5/2)
```

works. I know that this is because of precedence in R, but how to do I what I want, which is to multiply by the absolute value of `a`, and then assign the negative (while also assessing the possibility that `a == 0`)?

I know this is more of math and R question than statistics, so if it needs to be moved I will do so.

Comment: Like the OP I think this probably belongs on SO, but you don't need to move it yourself: if people agree with me it will be migrated for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
exponent <- function(a, pow) (abs(a)^pow)*sign(a)
```

Comment: Good one. More elegant than mine.

Comment: That's great. Never knew about sign().

Comment: If you don't have access to `sign`, you can usually get by using the mathematical definition of the signum function: x/abs(x) for x != 0 and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
b = rep(NA,length(a))       # create a vector of length equal to length of a
b[a>=0] =  ( a[a>=0])^(5/2) # deal with the non-negative elements of a
b[a< 0] = -(-a[a< 0])^(5/2) # deal with the negative elements of a
```

Maybe not the most efficient way to do it, but the idea should be usable.

Answer (score 0):

Your contradictory result stems from the fact that the power as a kind of multiplication binds stronger than the negation. I.e.,

```
-5^(5/2) = - ( 5^(5/2) ).
```

---

This kind of fractional power should rightly not be defined for negative arguments. It would be the solution of

```
x^2 = (-5)^5 = - 5^5
```

which is impossible to solve in real numbers.

Fractional powers of complex numbers is a can of worms that you really should not want to open.